# Examples of combinatoric problems solved by counting eulerian circuits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm looking for combinatoric problems that can be solved by counting eulerian circuits in directed graphs, i.e. by defining some graph and then counting all cycles passing through each edge exactly once.

One example I found is (a slight modification of) [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905624/prove-that-the-25-people-can-be-seated-in-this-way/905630#905630), where we have $n$ people belonging to $k$ disjunct groups of equal size, and  who shall be seated around a round-table. 
We now want to count the arrangements so that
  no pair of two people belonging to the same group have the same left-side-neighbor.

However, this example is quite particular, so I'd love to see some more general examples that illustrate when counting eulerian circuits can be helpful.

---

[BEST Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem), a polynomial method to count eulerian circuits in digraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0000111100101101$ is a string of $2^4$ bits with the property that any consecutive $4$ bits (including wrapping around to the front) represents a different $4$-bit binary string.  How many such strings are there with that property?  Generalize to $n\neq 4$.

Comment: Is the right construction for the graph then to take all 3 bit words over $\{0,1\}$ as nodes and put edges from each word to the two other 3-bit words that are created when putting a 0/1 onto the right of the word and deleting the first letter?

Comment: Yep.  I took this example from "Graph Theory with Applications" by Bondy and Murty where they go into more detail, but that's the essence of it.

Comment: The keyword "de Bruijn" might help search engines find this answer.